# I have a CMake file and I want to execute it in python

Tags: python, c++, function, cmake, compilation

the global problem: is that there is a GitHub library wrote by python, c++ and we need to use some c++ functions in python code so the authors propose to use CMake
https://github.com/acschaefer/ray_tracing

the local problem: I have a CMake file and I want to execute it in python (please check the link to GitHub, and go to the 4 steps)

edit: this is the code of CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.4 FATAL_ERROR)

project(ray_tracing LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall -Wextra")

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/python)
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_ray_tracing cpp/test_ray_tracing.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_ray_tracing Catch2::Catch2)

pybind11_add_module(ray_tracing_python cpp/ray_tracing_python.cpp)

add_custom_command(TARGET ray_tracing_python POST_BUILD 
     COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy 
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ray_tracing_python.so" 
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/python/raytracing/ray_tracing_python.so"
COMMENT "Copying shared library to Python directory")

execute_process(
     COMMAND python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; 
print(get_python_lib())" 
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES 
     OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

install(
    DIRECTORY python/raytracing
    DESTINATION ${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES})

enable_testing()
add_test(
    NAME test_cpp_implementation
    COMMAND test_ray_tracing)
add_test(
    NAME test_python_implementation
    COMMAND python -m pytest ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/python/test_raytracing.py)
```

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: CMake is used to build&install the lib. "Executing CMake in python" only makes sense, if you want to execute system commands shown in the build script via python (but this is probably more work than simply creating a command line/shell script).

Comment: @tadman I will try to explain more : I want to import ray_tracing_python in python a script where ray_tracing_python is written on c++

Comment: You have added the code, but forgot to add the error message or other evidence of "not working".

Comment: @Tsyvarev my goal is to use the above code to install the package in python

Comment: Hm, may be my wording was bad. You show the code, but is it working or not? If not, then  show (add to the question post) the error message it causes.